# How can I flatten a simple array without writing a loop operator explicitly?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'd like to turn a simple multidimensional array into an even more simple array.

Turn this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 456
        )
    ...
    [999] => Array
        (
            [id] => 789
        )
)
```

Into an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  123
    [1] => 456
    ...
    [999] => 789
)
```

I'd like to do so without foreach `foreach`.  Is this possible in PHP?

Here's how I can already solve it with a `foreach` loop:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $newArr[] = $a['id'];
}
$arr = $newArr;
```

I'd like to do it without looping.  Can you help?

Comment: Why would you like to do it without looping?

Comment: several people lately have posted about arrays and "Not looping" i don't understand why - they probably don't either

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: If you don't have to loop, it's usually more efficient not to loop.

Comment: avoiding a standard practice based on that 'premiss' is not efficient

Comment: An O(n) loop is the least of your worries as a PHP developer

Comment: look at how much more elegant array_map is than the foreach loop: `$arr = array_map('current',$arr);`

Comment: while you avoid the foreach() in php, your just using  several  for() loops in C. There are 4 for() loops in the source for array_map()

Comment: @Ryan And you basically guarantee no one will be able to read your code at a glance.

Comment: Looking ahead, PHP *may* have an [`array_column()`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column) function (though probably not in PHP 5.5.0).  `$ids = array_column($array, 'id');`

Comment: If don't have in this list http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php it don't exist

Comment: @Heberfa, correct. The function isn't even in the development source code at the moment. However, as you can see from my link above, the core developers voted in favour of including the function in the future.

Comment: I fixed the misleading title because, obviously, there is no way to flatten an array without a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `map` it:

```
$arr = array_map(function($element) {
    return $element['id'];
}, $arr);
```

Since `array_map` probably internally loops, you could do it truly without looping:

```
$arr = array_reduce($arr, function($arr, $element) {
    $arr[] = $element['id'];
    return $arr;
});
```

**But there's no reason to not loop.** There's no real performance gain, and the readability of your code is arguably decreased.

Comment: @Dagon Does `array_reduce` also loop?

Comment: So the second sentence is false?

Answer (score 8):

I admire your desire to have something approaching functional programming and implicit looping, but PHP is the wrong language for you. It does not express itself naturally in a functional style.

The `reset` function returns the first element in an array, so you can map that function over the array:

```
array_map('reset', $array)
```

However in PHP the fastest method is a simple `for` loop (not `foreach`, `for`). Here are a bunch of different methods of flattening. Only the functions containing `for` and `foreach` perform explicit looping and are included for comparison.

```
function flatten_for($arr) {
    $c = count($arr);
    $newarr = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $newarr[] = $arr[$i][0];
    }
    return $newarr;
}


function flatten_for_inplace($arr) {
    $c = count($arr);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $arr[$i] = $arr[$i][0];
    }
}


function flatten_foreach($arr) {
    $newarr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        $newarr[] = $value[0];
    }
    return $newarr;
}

function flatten_foreach_inplace($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $arr[$k] = $v[0];
    }
}

function flatten_foreach_inplace_ref($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as &$value) {
        $value = $value[0];
    }
}

function flatten_map($arr) {
    return array_map('reset', $arr);
}

function flatten_walk($arr) {
    array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k){$v = $v[0];});
}

function visitor($v, $k, &$a) {
    return $a[] = $v;
}

function flatten_walk_recursive($arr) {
    $newarr = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, 'visitor', $newarr);
    return $newarr;
}

function reducer($result, $item) {
    return $item[0];
}

function flatten_reduce($arr) {
    return array_reduce($arr, 'reducer', array());
}

function flatten_merge($arr) {
    return call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $arr);
}
```

Here is the timing code:

```
function buildarray($length) {
    return array_map(function($e){return array($e);}, range(0, $length));
}

function timeit($callable, $argfactory, $iterations) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        call_user_func($callable, call_user_func($argfactory));
    }
    return microtime(true) - $start;
}

function time_callbacks($callbacks, $argfactory, $iterations) {
    $times = array();
    foreach ($callbacks as $callback) {
        $times[$callback] = timeit($callback, $argfactory, $iterations);
    }
    return $times;
}

function argfactory() {
    return buildarray(1000);
}

$flatteners = array(
    'flatten_for', 'flatten_for_inplace', 'flatten_foreach',
    'flatten_foreach_inplace', 'flatten_foreach_inplace_ref',
    'flatten_map', 'flatten_walk', 'flatten_walk_recursive',
    'flatten_reduce', 'flatten_merge',
);

$results = time_callbacks($flatteners, 'argfactory', 1000);

var_export($results);
```

On an oldish MacBook Pro (Core 2 Duo, 2.66 GHz, 8GB, PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch) I get these results:

```
array (
  'flatten_for' => 12.793387174606,
  'flatten_for_inplace' => 14.093497991562,
  'flatten_foreach' => 16.71691608429,
  'flatten_foreach_inplace' => 16.964510917664,
  'flatten_foreach_inplace_ref' => 16.618073940277,
  'flatten_map' => 24.578175067902,
  'flatten_walk' => 22.884744882584,
  'flatten_walk_recursive' => 31.647840976715,
  'flatten_reduce' => 17.748590946198,
  'flatten_merge' => 20.691106081009,
)
```

The difference between the `for` and `foreach` methods is smaller on longer arrays.

Surprisingly (to me, anyway) `flatten_merge` is still slower than a plain `for` loop. I expected `array_merge_recursive` to be at least as fast if not faster since it's basically handing the whole job off to a C function!

Comment: You could just use `reset` instead of `current`, if you're worried about the status of the internal array pointers.

Comment: fascinating.  This is extremely helpful.  This answer needs more upvotes!  I look forward to testing on my own box soon.

Comment: `I admire your desire to have something approaching functional programming and implicit looping, but PHP is the wrong language for you.` Unfortunately, even in 2021 it is still true...

Answer (score 2):

For now, the easiest way is to use the array_column() function

```
$newArray = array_column($array, 'id');
```