# Need to change pdo fetching mode

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, psql

Using PHP **PDO** and **psql**
My query:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("select distinct extract(year from conclusion) from agreements_register where conclusion is not null");
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

it returns this:

```
[['date_part' => 2021],['date_part' => 2022]]
```

but I **need this**:

```
[2021, 2022]
```

Comment: You will always receive multiple arrays, you can then flatten them to get the desired result. For flattening, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944453/how-can-i-flatten-a-simple-array-without-looping

Comment: @Rylee 1. who told you that "You will always receive multiple arrays"? 2. Your question's title is misleading, **nowhere** does if flatten an array "without looping".

Comment: @young_protokaa42 but you were asking for the PDO fetch mode, not a post processing? Either way, using Google would have saved a lot of time for the lot of people including yourself

Comment: @YourCommonSense calling `fetchAll` returns an **array** which contains each row (as an **array**) hence - "multiple arrays". For the sake of this example, I didn't say "You will receive an array that can contain 0 more arrays which represent each row" as the OP seemed to already understand that. That was also not "my question" - it was a link to one that had a solution to flattening the array. What are you trying to do here? Prove something?

Comment: There are also different fetch modes which can return not just array but classes or objects - there's really no need to go into more detail as the answer was based on the context of the question.

Comment: @Rylee just to nudge you a bit but nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is example:

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

and it will output

```
Array(3)
(
    [0] =>
    string(5) => apple
    [1] =>
    string(4) => pear
    [2] =>
    string(10) => watermelon
)
```

and detail you can read this doc:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php